# Why does JavaScript allow both && (logical) and & (bitwise) in conditional statements?

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements, logical-operators

I recently found a piece of javascript which was evaluating null / undefined like so:

```
// The single & is on purpose!
if(x !== null & x !== undefined) {
    // Do this...
}
```

This looks like a very bad practice to me, but it seems to work.

As far am I am aware, these operators are supposed to perform two different tasks:

```
var x = 3; x &= 6; // No syntax errors.

var x = 3; x &&= 6; // Syntax error.

if(x == null && x == undefined) // No syntax errors.

if(x == null & x == undefined) // No syntax errors, but wrong operator usage?
```

Can anyone shed some light on this please?

Comment: It's not conditional AND and logical AND but logical AND (&&) and binary AND (&).

Comment: @WTK - updated title according to comment.

Comment: This got me. I was testing for flags like so: `27 & 4 === 0 ? false : true` outputs `true` while `(27 & 4) === 0 ? false : true` outputs false as expected.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When used like that, both the operators `&` and `&&` work as logical operators (even if the `&` operator isn't actually a logical operator). The practical difference is that `&&` uses [short circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation), and `&` doesn't.

There is no problem using the `&` operator, as long as it's possible to evaluate the second operand even if the first operand evaluates to false.

The `&&` operator can be used to keep the second operand from being evaluated, when the first operand determines if the second operand is possible to evaluate. For example:

```
if (x != null && x.prop == 42) { ... }
```

This is shorter than having to check one, then the other:

```
if (x != null) {
  if (x.prop == 42) { ... }
}
```

---

There is no `&&=` operator, as using short circuit evaluation in that case doesn't make sense.

Comment: `true & true === 1`, not `true & true === true`

Comment: @JanDvorak: Yes, the `&` operator isn't an actual logical operator, but when used with two boolean values, it *works* as a logical operator. I added a clarification in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

`expr1 & expr2` casts both arguments are cast to integers, then computes their bitwise AND. In case of booleans, the result is either `0` or `1` (NOT `false` or `true`). Zero is falsy and one is truthy, but there's still a difference in that both arguments are always evaluated.

`expr1 && expr2` returns `expr1` if it is falsy, otherwise it evaluates and returns `expr2`. `Expr2` is not evaluated if `expr1` is falsy.

Answer (score 0):

Using binary operations in conditions can be beneficial.

E.g. there is no logical 'XOR' operator, but a binary one:

if (cond1 ^ cond2) { // do something if one and only one of conditions is true  }

Binary operator applied to boolean evaluates the expression as integer (to 0 or 1), where the binary operation is valid and well defined.

Also the binary operation guarantees all the sub-expressions to be evaluated, where as `&&` short-circuits aka stops the evaluation when the expression is false. Knowing the difference allows choosing the best practice for the problem.

One could as well question, why does JavaScript allow a string, or object in comparison:

```
if ("foo") { // is true }
if ("false") { // is also true }
if (null) { // is false }
```